# Different execution plan for the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, database-performance, sql-execution-plan

I have two identical SQL Databases that contain nearly the same records in each of their tables. The only difference between them is that one lives on my local machine and the other one is in Azure. Yet, after investigating a performance issue I found out that the two databases produce different execution plans for some of the queries. To give you an example, here is a simple query that takes approximately 1 second to run.

```
select count(*) from Deposits
inner join households on households.id = deposits.HouseholdId
where CashierId = 'd89c8029-4808-4cea-b505-efd8279dc66d'
```

It is obvious that the inner join needs to be omitted as it doesn't contribute to the end result. Indeed, it is omitted on my local machine but this is not the fact for Azure. Here are two pictures visualizing the execution plans for my local machine and Azure, respectively.

[image: Local machine]

[image: Azure]

Just to give you some background on what happened, everything worked perfectly until I scaled down my Azure database to Basic 5 DTUs. Afterwards, some queries became extremely slow and I had no idea why. I scaled up the Db instance again but I saw no improvement. Then I rebuilt the indexes and noticed that if I rebuild them **in the correct order**, the queries will once again start performing as expected. Yet, I have absolutely no idea why I need to rebuild them in some specific order and, even less, how to determine the correct order. Now, I have issues with virtually all queries related to the `Deposits` table. I tried rebuilding the indexes but I saw no improvement whatsoever. I suspect that there is something to do with the PK index but I am not quite sure. The table contains approximately 300k rows.

Comment: One of the reasons why you are having different results in your local host and azure is that SQL Server optimizer chooses which logical join implement based on statistics, indexes, type of joins, number of estimated rows, etc.Check the statistics to fix your indexes.

Comment: That first query plan never references the `households`. I'd confidently say that the same query was not run on those 2 instances.

Comment: @abn From what I understand, rebuilding the indexes updates the statistics as well. Yet, I also tried running `EXEC sp_updatestats` but the execution plan didn't change.


@Larnu I guarantee that the same query is executed on both instances. If you think about, there is not point referencing the `households` table. There is exactly 1 household that corresponds to each deposit so the result of `count(*)` would never change regardless of the inner join. In other words, it would be best for the query optimizer to omit it, just like it did on my local machine.

Comment: _the inner join needs to be omitted as it doesn't contribute to the end result_. Only if the join doesn't increase or decrease the number of records. i.e. if `households.id` is not unique (more records) or there are missing `households.id` (less records). PK and FK go some way to giving the optimiser a clue about whether the joined table can actually be excluded.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid `households.id` is a PK and `deposits.HouseholdId` is a required FK, thus, the mapping will be one to one. If the FK was not required, it would make more sense to execute a clustered index scan or a nonclusted index scan with clustered index seek. Yet, the inner join would still be unnecessary in both scenarios. The only explanation that makes sense to me is that the database is somehow unsure whether it will find a corresponding record in the households table and, thus, it needs to check whether such record exists. As if it doesn't know whether the FK constraint is violated...

Comment: Perhaps the FK is untrusted on one system for some reason? I've definitely seem some unexpected plan changes (for the worse) when migrating to SQL Azure

Comment: There is always the possibility of parameter sniffing / bad cached plans

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried resetting the statistics and recompiling the execution plans but that doesn't help. I also checked whether the FK constraints are enforced and they are. I will try creating a fresh database and import the data to see whether the behavior will change in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Your databases may have the same schemas and approximate number of records,  but it's tough to make them identical.  Are you sure your databases are identical?

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'ProductVersion');
```

What about the hardware they are running on?  CPU? Memory? Disks? I mean it's Azure, right?  Hard to know what actual server hardware you are using.  SQL Server's query optimizer will adjust for hardware differences.  Additionally, even if the hardware and software were identical... simply the fact that databases are *used* differently can make them have differences in statistics.  The first time you run a query, it is evaluated, and optimized using statistics.  All subsequent calls of that query will use that initially cached query plan. Tables change over time, they get taller.  The shape of the data changes, meaning an old cached query plan can eventually fall out of favor.  Certain things can reshape the data and enact a change in statistics which in turn invalidate the query plan cache, such as such as rebuilding your indices. Try this.  To force a fresh query plan on each statement, add a

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

statement to the bottom of your queries.  Does that help or stabilize performance?  Furthermore - this is a strech - but can I assume that you aren't using that exact same query over and over?  It makes more sense that you haven't hardcoded that GUID and that we really have created a query plan for something that has `@CashierID` as parameter?  If so, then your existing  query plan could be victim of parameter sniffing, where the query plan you're pulling was optimized for some specific GUID and does poorly when you pass in anything else.

For more info about what that statement does, have a look [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/12/recompile-hints-and-execution-plan-caching/).  For more understanding on why it's hard to have identical databases take a look [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/11/t-sql-queries/multiple-plans-identical-query) and [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/12/sql-plan/different-plans-identical-servers).

Good luck!  Hope you can get it sorted.

Comment: Hello, Troy! Indeed, the Product Versions on the two instances are different (12 on azure vs 14 on my local machine). Also, for the test I am using the same query over and over again but, in reality, the application that connects to the database uses `@CashierID` as a parameter and the query is really slow as well. Something really strange is that the execution of the queries varies from 100ms to 1.2 - 1.5s. Maybe this can be a clue for what is happening, idk. Once again, the problem started once I scaled down the database in Azure. I will create a fresh copy and will try with it.

Comment: Also, `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` doesn't seem to do the trick. The execution times stays the same and the query plan doesn't change.

Comment: We're getting two different query plans because we have two different environments; software, hardware, and statistics. You should not expect them to be equal.  I think that "equality expectation" is occluding your actual goal, which is improving the performance of this query in Azure.  There are TONS of things you can do to optimize a query.  Starting with adding missing indices, reorganize, or rebuilding them, or perhaps adding more query hints to drive the query optimizer into the behavior you want. It will be hard to suggest an exact solution without knowing more about your Azure DB.